# DOM-Objects declared as JavaScript global variables

Tags: javascript, dom

Would it be a good practice to declare certain DOM-Objects as global JavaScript variables within a namespace?

Something like this:

```
var MyNS = {};

$(document).ready(function(){
    MyNS.domObject1 = $('#id1');
    MyNS.domObject2 = $('#id2');
});
```

Comment: Typically, you cache DOM references in order to write faster code. However, saving a bunch of DOM references in a namespace may slow things down by holding reference to things that do not need to stay in memory. Typically, you will cache DOM references only within a method/function to allow garbage collection to proceed normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to consider:

**1)** Creating global variables in JavaScript is not a good practice, every global variable is actually a property of the `window` global object, which already has a lot of properties. This means that, if you add global variables you might be messing with existing variables, or some other code may overwrite your variables.

Solutions for this: Store all the global variables you need on a single object, and make sure nothing else in tha page will use that object. Or don't even use global variables at all.

**2)** Why would you need to store those elements globally if you already can access them with the IDs? Even if you want to have a direct reference somewhere, you can store them as variables of the `$(document).ready` funciton, and they'll be visible to all te functions declared there.

**3)** To fully prevent the use of global variables you can smartly wrap your codes in anonymous auto-executable functions like this one:

```
(function () { ... }());
```

All the variable you declare inside this type of functions will be only be visible inside that function, and the function will execute inmediatelly, and through garbage-collection you can solve any performance issues realated to having too much references to DOM objects, just by using this anonymous functions.

**4)** If all that fails, then yes, you're making the right decision by storing all the elements in an object, instead of making a global variable for each element.